# How to extract address from c-string

Tags: c, pointers, char, memory-address, gdbserver

I'm writing my program and i need to get a pointer from c-string. For example, i have a string like "0x3b021e01" and as an output i want a legal pointer void *ptr == 0x3021e101.

I tried this approach:

```
char *addr = "0x3021e101"; // this address is just an example of 32-bit addr

uint32_t iaddr = from_ch_to_hex(addr); // iaddr == 0x3021e101

void *data_buf = (void *)iaddr; // data_buf = 0x3021e101

uint32_t reg_val = *(uint32_t *)data_buf;
```

But I get Segmentation fault. What's wrong here? How can i fix it?

Comment: Well, is it a legal uint32_t address?  It doesn't look right - alignment wrong.

Comment: Hang on - the address is more than 32 bits.  Is this a 64-bit pointer?

Comment: What is the extra '01' on the end for?

Comment: OK, now it's clearer.  Does your architecture and/or memory-manager support access to non-aligned memory addresses?

Comment: Even more interesting - is this code running on the debugger server or remote client?

Comment: Yeah, it looks as if the problem is in alignment. It's running on the server. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0x3b021e101 is an odd number, so you would expect alignment errors.

By the way, unless you know by other means that the address is valid,
say by having a pointer to that address, why don't you just use that
pointer?